# Empty list view (new module on odoo 12)

Tags: odoo

I have made a new module, everything seems to be ok (i can CRUD product), but list of products is empty. 
What can cause such trouble? Something wrong with

```
<!-- Action to open list -->
<act_window id="action_for_menu"
  name="List of products"
  res_model="x.x"
  view_type="form"
  view_mode="tree,form" /> 


<!-- List view. -->
<record id="x_list_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">x.list</field>
  <field name="model">x.x</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree>
      <field name="name"/>
      <field name="descr"/>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Do the user you use for testing has the access rights on model `x.x`?

Comment: The reason of my trouble was in field "active", which i made default=False. The active field is used to inactivate records, and by default only active records will be shown.

Comment: If possible, edit this default in your question, and if possible answer yourself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of my trouble was in field "active", which i made default=False. The active field is used to inactivate records, and by default only active records will be shown.